# How can I restart yum?

Tags: yum, cpu-usage

on my server, yum is using a LOT of system resources. My friend suggested to kill -9 it, but I want to know I'll be able to restart it first. Preferably without rebooting the whole server.

However, I'd also like some alternatives, I'd rather know WHY yum is taking up all these resources. I'm fairly new to running servers, so I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: [When should I use kill -9](http://aplawrence.com/SCOFAQ/FAQ_scotec6killminus9.html) and [Useless use of kill -9](http://sial.org/howto/shell/kill-9/) and [Whose idea was this?](http://sial.org/howto/shell/kill-9/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to restart yum like any other service,

```
/sbin/service yum restart
```

You can try to trace what the yum process is doing by using

```
strace -p PID
```

(where PID is the process ID that you can look up using top)

You can look up the strace man page for more information

```
man strace
```

Comment: strace unknown command, although now I've rechecked top, and yum isn't at the top of it anymore, or even on it. This is driving me nuts. I have ridiculous load averages

Comment: You probably have to install strace using 'yum install strace'

Also check the output of top or free and see how much swap is being used. That might indicate that you are out of RAM and some process is now thrashing and using your swap and causing your queue to grow. You can also rearrange top to arrange by memory used by typing M.

Comment: root     17145  3.8  0.8  22684 13532 ?        R    07:48   0:07 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/yum info

Yum is currently in use by that

Comment: As the other comment said, yum is not a service

Answer (score 4):

Yum is not a service it is a command, so you don't restart it like a service - you kill it and if need be re-run it.

However interrupting yum can leave yum in an inconsistent state, which can be a problem when you next try to use it.

If you do interrupt yum, you may want to have a look at the `yum-complete-transaction` command.

You may also want to look at the `yum clean ...` commands

man yum 
man yum-complete-transaction